# How to configure Hybrid memory in Gem5

Tags: gem5

Can anyone help to to configure the hybrid memory system in gem5 simulator.
I want to configure 2 memories one is HBM and other DDR4 into the system could someone help me from which file to start and modify to do so

I am working with Gem5 and running in emulation mode with x86 ISA, while using the se.py there is only an option to provide the type of memory for the whole system how to configure whole memory as the flat address system as hybrid memory where required two memory types with different configurations.